# Tension as a function of angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, momentum

Three equal masses are connected by two light inextensible strings. The middle one is imparted a velocity $v$. All collisions are elastic. Find the tension in the thread as a function of the angle $\theta$ made by the vertical and the strings.

[image: “Diagram”]

I have no idea how to proceed in such a question.
(Only hint in my mind is that we have to use impulse-momentum theorem. But I don’t know how to proceed after that)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot give you a complete answer per the rules of this forum I can guide you on how to proceed.

1. **Establish the degrees of freedom of the system.** You know there are three masses (each with 2 DOF) and two constraints (each with -1 DOF) for a total of $2 \times 3-2 \times 1 = 4$ DOF. But because of symmetry we can ignore 2 of those DOF. The side to side movement, and the rotation. So we are left with 2 DOF.

   A reasonable choice for the two degrees of freedom is the $y$ position of the center mass, and the included angle $\theta$ between the two side masses. But feel free to choose other ones, as long as you can completely describe all the possible configurations of the system with those two parameters.
2. **Establish the kinematics of all the masses**. Based on those two DOF find the expressions for the location of the masses. Again these locations should be a function of the two DOF variables picked above, and everything else should be a constant value.
3. **Establish to velocity and acceleration of all the masses**. From the positions above use the chain rule of calculus to find the velocities and accelerations of the masses as a function of the DOF and their derivatives. For example $\vec{\rm vel} = f(y,\theta,\dot{y},\dot{\theta})$ where $\dot{\square}$ is the first derivative of the parameter with time. Also $\ddot{\square}$ would be the second derivative with time.
4. **Write the equations of motion**. Use a free body diagram to find all forces acting on each body for *any* configuration given by the DOF. There are going to be only two equations of motion due to symmetry.
5. **Solve the problem**. Two equations and two unknowns is solvable, so you solve for 2nd derivatives of DOF, and then use an integration scheme to find out what will happen in the future. You night get lucky and get something solvable analytically, or else it will need some kind of numeric solver.

The hardest part is usually **3.** with second hardest **5.** which involves deciding what is know and what is unknown in any given situation. With problems involving contacts it gets tricky to manage the system state (all the positions and velocities) before and after the contact.